# Should thermal compund be replaced after the heat sink is taken off?

Tags: cooling, overheating, heatsink, fan

I recently took apart a Dell Inspiron N5110 Laptop to clean the cooling fan and other stuff. This involved removing the heat sink as well. I did not put on new thermal compound when I put things back. Should I have done this? The laptop now shuts down every time I begin a game. There was hardly any thermal paste left when I took things apart.

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely! Should clean off all the original compound and then put new compound on top of CPU and spread out evenly before placing heatsink back on top of CPU.

Answer (score 1):

**YES!**

The reasoning is simple, the entire purpose of the material between the CPU and the Heatsink is to minimize air between between the two, thus increasing the heat transference to the heatsink to be drawn out through the radiator and fans.

When you first install a CPU, the thermal paste is more of a liquid, and "cures" with very little air. When you remove the heatsink later, that paste is more of a solid and re-seating the heatsink without new paste introduces more air and creates a poor conducting surface.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, absolutely be sure to spread the compound evenly across the CPU surface to provide maximum conductivity.  Also, check the fan connector for proper seating laptops are difficult to replace fans in and the connectors can get dislodged when replacing the case.  This would definitely account for shutdowns when the CPU is under stress, games for example!